# How to build an Offline Electron app with maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, electron

I want to create an app with electron to work in places where an Internet connection won't be available.

This app requires to show a map based on the user geolocation. So after reading a bit, I found that there are some solutions but I cannot be sure if these work offline (The area I need to see in the map it will be always the same, so maybe a cache solution or a previously download map will work).

In a mobile app, I can use Google Maps which downloads the maps, but on a website I don't think this is possible.

Another option could be Kothic, but I have some doubts as it hasn't been active since several years ago.

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't support offline mode. The corresponding feature request in Google issue tracker is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827808.

Answer (score -1):

You can download vector data and package it with your electron app, then render it with several different open source libraries (mapbox, Leaflet...).

If you absolutely need satellite / aerial imagery, then you will need to download raster tiles; most services with such tiles require not to package those tiles, but per user local cache is usually authorised, like for mobile Google Maps. It is possible implementing such user cache, there should be some plugins for that as well.

Comment: Could you explain how? I mean, from where to download th evector data, how to package and how to render? SO far I have th mbtiles, but I'm not able to render those.